# How can I flip the x axis (180 degrees) using Plotly in R

Tags: r, plotly, histogram

I created a probability histogram using the following code:

```
set.seed(99)
x <- rnorm(1000)
fig1 <- plot_ly (y = ~x, type = 'histogram', histnorm = 'probability') %>% 
        layout(title = "Frequency Distribution",
               xaxis = list(title = "Frequency", mirror = TRUE  ))
fig1
```

The above code gives me the following:
[image: plot1]

as can be seen in the code I tried to flip the plot 180 degrees using `mirror` in the `xaxis` part. however, it does not work. I want to have such a plot:

[image: plot2]

Any ideas to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `autorange = "reversed"`

```
plot_ly (y = ~x, type = 'histogram', histnorm = 'probability') %>% 
  layout(
    title = "Frequency Distribution",
    xaxis = list(title = "Frequency", autorange = "reversed")
  )
```

[image: hist]

Comment: How would you put the vertical axis on the right hand side?

Comment: Nevermind, you can move the yaxis on the other side with `yaxis = list(side = "right")`